# Error in adding annotations to independent facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

plot stomatal conductance among different CO2, species and days.

```
p<-ggplot(data=gssummary,aes(x=factor(day),y=Cond,fill=factor(co2)))+geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "dodge",width=0.4,colour="black")+geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Cond-ci,ymax=Cond+ci), width=.1,position = position_dodge(0.4))+theme_bw()+theme(panel.grid=element_blank())+labs(x="Day",y=expression(plain("g"["s"])))+facet_grid(~species)+theme(axis.ticks=element_line(size=rel(0.1)))+theme(axis.text=element_text(size = rel(0.5),family = "Times"))+theme(axis.title=element_text(size = 7,family = "Times"))+theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,3,0,0),"cm"))+theme(strip.text=element_text(size=rel(0.6),family = "Times"),strip.background=element_rect(colour = "white",fill = "white"))+theme(panel.border=element_rect(colour = "black",size = 1))+guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL))+scale_fill_grey(start = 1,end = 0.75,labels=c(expression(plain("aCO"["2"])),expression(plain("eCO"["2"]))))
```

add the information of significance to the plot(The difference was only significant between aco2 and eco2 on 2nd Sep,2016 in species 0)

```
siglabel<-data.frame(species=c("0","1"),label=c("*"," "))
p+geom_text(x=1,y=0.6,aes(label=label),data = siglabel)
```

**Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:label**

[stomatal conductance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5ZeC.jpg)

[gssummary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEFAk.jpg)

I've tried but still can not solve this problem. Please tell me how to solve it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you add "ggsumary" as code instead of a picture (maybe with `dput` but even if you just copy and paste it from R)?  But I can see that "siglabel" has two rows but you only have one set of x and y coordinates.  Maybe you want to plot only a subset of "siglabel"?

Comment: I‘ve known what's the problem is and have solved it. But still thank you for your consideration of my question.

Comment: You can put your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem is that the length of label is not the same as the length of gssummary. I changed the code as follows.

siglabel<-data.frame(species=c("0","0","1","1"),co2=c("0","1","0","1"),label=c("*"," "," "," "))

p+geom_text(x=1,y=0.6,aes(label=label),data = siglabel)